# Is there a simple method using PHP for posting to Twitter without managing user logins or getting tweets?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I've seen there is some other discussion about this, however, none of the other threads I've read have targetted my situation.

For one, I do not need to get any Tweets *from* Twitter. I only need to send **to** Twitter.

For another, I don't need to have multiple accounts or different Twitter users. I can already ensure the page will only be seen by the one authorized user, so I can save any necessary login information in one configuration file and be done.

I am only posting occasionally from one web site, to one Twitter feed, and only one user will be logged onto the the web site that will send the tweet.

I am hoping to find a simple tutorial or script that can allow me to cut to the bare bones and just send tweets to my Twitter account.

However, all the tutorials and scripts I've seen so far have been too elaborate, handling logins, sessions, authenticating multiple users, and so on.

Is there any way I can get simple oAuth PHP code to accomplish what I'm describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would help

http://code.google.com/p/dabr/source/browse/trunk/common/twitter.php

http://code.google.com/p/dabr/source/browse/trunk/common/OAuth.php

Answer (score 1):

This should help or at least point you in the right direction.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php

Answer (score 1):

You can use ZF component

get `accessToken` only once, keep it as serialized string anywhere

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html